# Find strings from an cell array and create a new cell array

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I want to find the strings from an cell array `(m x n)` and add those identified strings in new cell array `(m x n)`, by using matlab, for example:

```
Human(i,1)={0
1
34
eyes_two
55
33
ears_two
nose_one
mouth_one
631
49
Tounge_one}
```

I want to remove the numbers and have just strings

```
New_Human(i,1)={eyes_two
ears_two
nose_one
mouth_one
tounge_one}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment it sounds like all your data is being stored as strings. In that case you can use the following method to remove all strings which represent a valid number.

```
H = {'0'; '1'; '34'; 'eyes_two'; '55'; '33'; 'ears_two'; 'nose_one'; 'mouth_one'; '631'; '49'; 'Tounge_one'};

idx = cellfun(@(x)isnan(str2double(x)), H);
Hstr = H(idx)
```

Output

```
Hstr = 
    'eyes_two'
    'ears_two'
    'nose_one'
    'mouth_one'
    'Tounge_one'
```

The code determines which strings do not represent valid numeric values. This is accomplished by checking if the `str2double` function returns a `NaN` result on each string. If you want to understand more about how this works I suggest you read the documentation on `cellfun`.

Comment: Hi @jodag, thanks for suggesting the method, but for some reason in my script, idx is taking numbers and characters (Parameter values) as '1', hence Hstr is same as H

Comment: @Mohammed Nadaf I updated the answer based on your comment.